# Insanely slow Mongodb group query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to aggregate $sum between 2 dates stored as UTC strings (yyyy-mm-dd-hh). It takes 5+ seconds to get the results. My collection has 5 million+ docs.

```
      { 
          $match: {
            start: { 
              $gte: '2020-08-01-00',
              $lte: '2021-08-01-00'
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: { 
                symbol: '$symbol'
            },
            unverifiedCount: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: { $eq: ['$isVerified', false] }, then: '$count', else: 0
                    }
                }
            },
            verifiedCount: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: { $eq: ['$isVerified', true]}, then: '$count', else: 0
                    }
                }
              }
          }
        }, {
          $sort: {
            unverifiedCount: -1
          }
        }
```

Tried using $toDateString but performance remained the same

Comment: not so sure, but instead of relying on mongo itself, why not use the backend server? first try to filter then do the grouping on your backend language

Comment: Are the dates indexed? Also, they should be ISODates, not strings

Comment: In your `$match` stage, the `start` field type and the input types must be the same for comparing. Since, you have specified, string values it is assumed the `start` is of string too.  See [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/).

Comment: **Never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects. Where are your indexes?

Comment: Is there a way to transform yyyy-mm-dd-hh into yyyy-mm-ddThh:00:00Z using Mongodb shell? Mongodb ISODate and Date don't accept the former